# How to store object in Mongo DB as value?

Tags: php, mongodb

Now, when I add values to Mongodb using PHP it stores as array:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("591e9b60470e6c500f3c9869"),"value" : [ "mama", "papa" ] }
```

How to store data for value as object: `{"mama" : 1, "papa" : 2}`?

I tried:

```
$data = array("value" => array("mama" => 1, "papa" => 2))

$this->collection->insert($data);
```

It is inserted as array!

Comment: Are you positive you are looking at the correct document or even collection ( or database for that matter ). The PHP form you are showing serializes as an object and not an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using these lines -

```
$data = (object) ["value" => (object) ["mama" => 1, "papa" => 2]]

$this->collection->insert($data);
```

It'll create object with mentioned properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
 db.products.insert(
    [
      { _id: 11, item: "pencil", qty: 50, type: "no.2" },
      { item: "pen", qty: 20 },
      { item: "eraser", qty: 25 }
    ]
 )

 or
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("591c382a82956dc8a500002e"),
     "name" : "alpesh",
     "email" : "admin@gmail.com",
     "contact_number" : "0123456789",
     "position" : "devloper",
     "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-05-17T11:46:50.000Z"),
     "created_at" : ISODate("2017-05-17T11:46:50.000Z")
  }
```